# Sempre manter o mesmo nome de um arquivo PDF no upload

Tags: php, pdf

Como posso manter o mesmo nome de um arquivo no momento do upload, por exemplo se a pessoa escolher um arquivo com o nome planilha.pdf eu possa sempre grava-lo com um nome fixo, como documento.pdf, hoje faço isso no meu script:

```
$arquivo = $_FILES["arquivo_pdf"];
$arquivo_nome = $arquivo["name"];

// Move o arquivo para o diretório especificado
set_time_limit(0);
$diretorio = "../diretorio/";
$arquivo_temporario = $_FILES['arquivo_pdf']["tmp_name"];   
move_uploaded_file($arquivo_temporario, $diretorio.$arquivo_nome);
```

Sendo $arquivo_nome é o que pretendo sempre deixar com o mesmo nome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muito simples. Basta você definir `$arquivo_nome` como `documento.pdf`.

```
$arquivo = $_FILES["arquivo_pdf"];
$arquivo_nome = 'documento.pdf';

// Move o arquivo para o diretório especificado
set_time_limit(0);
$diretorio = "../diretorio/";
$arquivo_temporario = $_FILES['arquivo_pdf']["tmp_name"];   
move_uploaded_file($arquivo_temporario, $diretorio.$arquivo_nome);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @gpupo, valeu mesmo.